# Can't get color or textcolor to work

Tags: xetex, color

I'm new to latex. I'm using a template on overleaf.com.
I'm trying to change the color of some of the text, but it remains grey.
Here's a simplified sample of the tex file:

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Undergraduate}
\textcolor{red}{Information Retrieval} \\
{\color{red}Operating Systems} \\
Unix Tools and Scripting \\
\end{document}  \documentclass[]{article}
```

I tried using both `\color` and `\textcolor`, but neither of them change the color of the text.

Here's a sample of the cls file:

```
% Intro Options
\ProvidesClass{deedy-resume-openfont}[2014/04/30 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

% Package Imports
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=0.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}

% Color definitions
\definecolor{date}{HTML}{666666} 
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{2b2b2b} 
\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{6A6A6A}
\definecolor{subheadings}{HTML}{333333}

% Set main fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Color=primary, Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text, Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-ExtraLight}
\newcommand{\custombold}[1]{\color{subheadings}\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Reg}\selectfont #1 \normalfont}

% Subeadings command
\titleformat{\subsection}{\color{subheadings}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries\uppercase}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\newcommand{\runsubsection}[1]{\color{subheadings}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries\uppercase {#1} \normalfont}
```

Here's a link to the original template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/deedy-resume/sqdbztjjghvz#.Vr5XHWgrJhE

What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks.

Comment: `\setmainfont[Color=primary, Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}` is the culprit, I think. If this is set as `\setmainfont[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}` only, the colors will work

Answer (score 4):

The class file sets

```
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{2b2b2b} 
%%%
\setmainfont[Color=primary, Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}
```

i.e. the font color is fixed to the primary color definition (until this is changed).

The solution is to reset the main font using

```
\setmainfont[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}
```

in the main document file (do not really edit the class -- although the class does wrongly load `hyperref` in between!)

Class file:

```
\ProvidesClass{deedy-resume-openfont}[2014/04/30 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

% Package Imports
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=0.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


% Color definitions
\definecolor{date}{HTML}{666666} 
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{2b2b2b} 
\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{6A6A6A}
\definecolor{subheadings}{HTML}{333333}

% Set main fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Color=primary, Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text, Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-ExtraLight}
\newcommand{\custombold}[1]{\color{subheadings}\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Reg}\selectfont #1 \normalfont}

% Date command
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{5mm} % start everyth
\newcommand{\lastupdated}{\begin{textblock}{60}(165,0)
\color{date}\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-ExtraLight}\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont 
Last Updated on
\today
\end{textblock}}

% Name command
\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
    \centering{
        \sffamily
        \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\fontsize{40pt}{10cm}\selectfont #1 
        \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2
    } \\
    \vspace{5pt}
    \centering{ \color{headings}\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #3}
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
    \vspace{-15pt}
}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

% Headings command
\titleformat{\section}{\color{headings}
\scshape\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\fontsize{16pt}{24pt}\selectfont \raggedright\uppercase}{} {0em}{}

% Subeadings command
\titleformat{\subsection}{\color{subheadings}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries\uppercase}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\newcommand{\runsubsection}[1]{\color{subheadings}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries\uppercase {#1} \normalfont}

% Descriptors command
\newcommand{\descript}[1]{\color{subheadings}\raggedright\scshape\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont {#1 \\} \normalfont}

% Location command
\newcommand{\location}[1]{\color{headings}\raggedright\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont {#1\\} \normalfont}

% Section seperators command
\newcommand{\sectionsep}[0]{\vspace{8pt}}

% Bullet Lists with fewer gaps command
\newenvironment{tightemize}{\vspace{-\topsep}\begin{itemize}\itemsep1pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-\topsep}}
```

Document:

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\setmainfont[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Undergraduate}
\textcolor{red}{Information Retrieval} \\
{\color{red}Operating Systems} \\
Unix Tools and Scripting \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Would upvote, but it's a new account and I don't have enough reputation it seems.

Comment: @j9s3: Now you should be able to upvote and accept ;-)